# Batch Edit to Articles

Tags: joomla-3.4

I would like to add the following code to over 50 articles:

Is there a way to add the code to my articles in one shot? I attempted to do this with the Batch Process, but the functionality didn't exist.

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers

Carlton

Comment: Check out https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/dbreplacer and https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/snippets

Comment: what is the following code? is it code or content?

Comment: Hi FFrewin, I have decided to give regularlabs a try. However, each time I attempt to install the application I get the error message 'Unable to find install package'.

Comment: I'm also getting the following error: JFolder::create: Path not in open_basedir paths.

Comment: Hi FFRewin, I'm having a nightmare installing the package, do you recommend any other package

Comment: When you reply to someone in comments, you need to reference him like @Carltonp, otherwise it's very unlikely to get notified for your comment reply. Regular Labs, requires some experience, as it directly changes the database - so be careful. It's not the extension, it's something with your site/environment that won't let you install it. http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4599/how-to-deal-with-jfoldercreate-path-not-in-open-basedir-paths-unable-to-crea

Comment: @ffrewin, I'm following the guide from the link you provided Login to Joomla Administartor panel.
Go to Global Configuration
Click "Server"
Change the path from /public_html/tmp to "tmp"
Login to control Panel(CPanel)
Open File Manager
Open Folder "libraries"
Open Folder "joomla"
Open Folder "filesystem" However, I can't find the Folder "libraries". Can you let know how to get to that folder?

Comment: If you have another specific question/problem that is not answered anywhere else in here, create a new question. Consider to add all the details, to narrow down the problem, so you can get the best possible answers. Avoid to have extended chats on comments, especially if the chats are about different problems.

Comment: @Carltonp - If you post a support ticket in Regular Labs, Peter is a super nice guy. He will likely know what's preventing the install and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Is there a relation between those 50 articles, like they are all in the same category?  If so, you could create a template override for the article layout and do a conditional where if catid=101, then add code.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to create a module and then assign that module to all your pages, and then, in your template file (the index.php file), make sure you display the module only when you are in an article. You can check if you are in an article the following way:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$option = $jinput->getCmd('option');
$view   = $jinput->getCmd('view');
if ($option == 'com_content' && $view == 'article'){
    // We are in an article. Add the module tag here.
}
```

Comment: @ffrewin, as you know, I have finally managed to install regularlabs, however the ability to add code to a number of articles in one shot using DB Replacer can only be achieved by replacing code. This isn't really what I would like. I would just like to add code to a number of articles without having to replace code.

Comment: I take it back the Regular Content Templater does the trick. Thank you